# Inverse multiplication in python classes

Tags: python, class

I am using this code

```
class Score(object):
    def __init__(self, goal=0, score=0):
        self.goal = goal
        self.score = score

    def __mul__(self, other):
        return Score((self.goal * other), (self.score * other))

def main():
    s2 = Score(3, 12)
    s2 = s2 * 2
    print(s2)
```

But my code breaks when i say s2 = 2 * s2 in main function, any idea on how to fix it?

Comment: How does it break? What is your error? What do you expect *should* happen? Details please.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to define [`__rmul__`](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__rmul__) as well.

```
class Score(object):
    def __init__(self, goal=0, score=0):
        self.goal = goal
        self.score = score

    def __mul__(self, other):
        return Score((self.goal * other), (self.score * other))

    def __rmul__(self, other):
        # This assumes multiplication is always commutative, i.e.,
        # Score * other == other * Score 
        return self * other
```

The expression `2 * s2` first tries to invoke `(2).__mul__(s2)`. Since `int.__mul__` doesn't know how to multiply an `int` with an instance of `Score`, it returns `NotImplemented`, which signals the interpreter to try `s2.__rmul__(2)` next.